# Mark symlink to folder outside a project as a source folder

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I have a scala project like this:

[image]

And I symlink another folder `/tmp/outside` as `scala/outside` (`outside` may contain subdiretories), how can I make it appear as a source folder in intellij?